# Can I store a Corian sink outside

Tags: storage

I have two pieces of Corian - one is solid with some small wood braces underneath and the other is rather large with a built in sink.  I don't know the material the sink is made of.  It is not metal.

The pieces are in my basement and are fine there over the years but I need to put outside to work on the basement.  I expect them to get snowed on.  I'm thinking some deck blocks and pavers to support the big piece and maybe put the straight piece over the sink then cover with a tarp and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Corian can be stored outdoors. It is stable in freeze/ thaw environments and U.V. resistant.

Outdoor tables are often made from Corian. See below:

https://www.corian.com/corian-r-technique-outdoor-spaces